# How to check tool tip in selenium web driver?

Tags: selenium, tooltip

Somebody please suggest me how can i test tool tip text in selenium web driver.
I am trying to find out but its not work:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement web1 = driver.findElement(By.id("txtEmailId"));
        action.moveToElement(web1).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: if it's mouse hover tool tip then try action.moveToElement(web1).build().perform();

Answer (score 0):

Use Java Robot for the UI interaction; Robot is used here for controlling Mouse actions.

```
WebElement targetElement = driver.findElement(By.id("txtEmailId"));
Point coordinates = targetElement.getLocation();
Robot robot = new Robot(); 
robot.mouseMove(coordinates.getX(), coordinates.getY() + 65); //Number 65 should vary

Thread.sleep(3000);
String tooltip = driver.findElement(By.id("txtEmailId"")).getAttribute("title");
System.out.println(tooltip);
```

Answer (score 0):

to capture ToolTip you can first perform Mouse hover and then you can call getText() method which will capture the text in String format.

Below link will guide you for the same.

http://learn-automation.com/how-to-capture-tooltip-in-selenium-webdriver/